# Gerar uma janela de pop-up no R

Tags: r, bat

Tenho um código em R que gera de saída uma mensagem informando se uma série está atualizada ou não. Rodo o código através de um arquivo .bat no Windows e ele gera um arquivo txt.
Tentei gerar um pop-up usando o pacote `svDialogs`, mas ele só gera o pop-up se eu executar o código pelo próprio R. Existe alguma forma de o pop-up ser exibido executando o código atráves do arquivo .bat?

Código que estou usando para mostrar o pop-up dentro do R:

```
dlg_message(mensagem, type = "ok")
```

Código do arquivo .bat que estou usando para executar o código em R:

```
cd C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.1\bin\i386
Rscript.exe C:\Users\User\Documents\R\consulta_ettj.R
```

Obs.: O código funciona normalmente sendo executado pelo .bat, só o pop-up que não é gerado.

Comment: A diferença está em que uma seção é interativa e a outra não. Para maiores informações veja `?interactive()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Precisa ser usando **`svDialogs`**? Aparentemente, ele só funciona no modo interativo ou nem nele (rodando dentro do **`RStudio`**).

---

> - *Existe alguma forma de o pop-up ser exibido executando o código através do arquivo .bat?*

- **1)** Sim, usando o **[tc/ltk](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tcltk/versions/3.6.2)**, opção que funciona fora do RStudio, digo, fora do modo interativo, e que já vem com as ultimas versões do **[r](/questions/tagged/r)**.
- **2)** A alternativa com uso do **[tc/ltk](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tcltk/versions/3.6.2)** e que funciona no **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)**/**[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)**
- a) Ou você entra na pasta do R executa:

  ```
  cd /d "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.1\bin\i386" && Rscript.exe Script.R
  ```
- b) Ou pode fazer o seu **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)**/**[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** criar o seu **`Rscript`** para excutá-lo em **tempo de execução**, e sem usar **`escaping`**:

---

---

```bat
@;echo off && setlocal && mode 70,10 & color 0A & title ..\%~dpnx0
@;
@;<con: pushd "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.5\bin\i386\." 2>nul && =;(
@;cmd/r %__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /vb @; ^<"%~f0">"%temp%\RScr.r")=;
@;R.exe --vanilla <"%tmp%\RScr.r">nul 2>&1 &&(del/q "%tmp%\RScr.r"
@;endlocal & goto :EOF )||(del/q "%temp%\RScr.r" 2>nul && endlocal
@;echo[Error: Path para R/Rscript nao encontrado^!! & goto :EOF);=
@;
@; Nas linhas abaixo entraram o código R, mas sem iniciar com "@;"

require(tcltk)

msgBox <- tkmessageBox(title = "tc/ltk SO Q431647",
                       message = "Hello, world! by tcltk!", icon = "info", type = "ok")

msgBox <- tkmessageBox(title = "zOk Click..",
                       message = "z0k", type = "ok")
```

---

**Obs.:** As linhas do código acima, são executadas pelo  interpretador de comando, e ele saí da execução em: **`goto :EOF`**, também são filtradas para o **`script R`**, todas que **não** começam com os caráteres **`@;`**, então perceba que seu código em **`R`**, terá essa limitação apenas, nenhuma linha pode começar com **`@;`**

---

> - Para uso convencional

- **1)** Salve esse código no seu **`Script.R`**:

---

```bat
require(tcltk)

msgBox <- tkmessageBox(title = "tc/ltk SO Q431647",
                      message = "Hello, world! by tcltk!", icon = "info", type = "ok")

msgBox <- tkmessageBox(title = "zOk Click..",
                       message = "z0k", type = "ok")
```

---

- **2)** Salve esse código no seu **`bat/cmd`**:

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal && mode 70,10 && color 0A && title %~dpnx0

pushd "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.1\bin\i386\." && R.exe --vanilla <"d:\caminho\do\seu\RScriptR.r"
popd && endlocal && goto :EOF
```

---

> - Comentando o **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)**/**[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)**:

---

```bat
echo off
inibir eco do comando na sáida do prompt

setlocal
herdar as variáveis da sessão ambiente atual

mode 70,10
muda tamanho da janela p 70 colunas 10 linhas

color 0A 
muda cor de fundo para preto e a fonte verde claro

title %~dpnx0
atribuir titulo da janela com: d=drive p=path n=name x ext do bat

pushd "c:\..."
faz a pasta atual ser salva para retorno (via popd) e traz para pila a pasta
  
&& (
caso a execução anterior se deu se erro, vai executar as ações dentro enfileiradas dentro do ()

cmd  /r type "%~f0"
vai direcionar o conteúdo do arquivo bat (fullpath %~f0) para o findstr

findstr /vb ^@ |%__APPDIR__%findstr /vb ^@; >"%temp%\RScr.r")
vai ignorar todas as linhas iniciadas por "@;", e redirecionar como conteúdo para o arquivo >"%temp%\RScr.r" (gravar nele)

@;R.exe --vanilla <"%tmp%\RScr.r" 2>&1>&0
executar o escript apontado pelo operador < file. ignorando arquivos e avariável R_LIBS_USER local do usuário.

&& (del "%temp%\RScr.r"
se a execução se deu sem erro, vai apagar o script criado (temporário), finalizar o local, (endlocal) e ir para o final do arquivo, sair.. (executando o que esta em ()

||(del "%temp%\RScr.r" 2>nul && ;endlocal 
@;echo[Error: Path para R/Rscript não encontrado^!! & goto :EOF )
se a execução decorrer em erro(s), vai exibir uma mensagem, sugerindo que o erro está no caminho, vai apagar o script temporário, finalizar o local, (endlocal) e ir para o final do arquivo, sair..

@;:: Nas linhas abaixo entra o código R, mas sem iniciar com "@;"
Apenas um comentário lembrado da limitação para autoria de código em script R
```

---